# maven dependencies in eclipse doesn't match pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the following dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, when I look at the maven dependencies in eclipse, I see these:

[image]

Where are those additional dependencies coming in from? Is it coming in as part of one of the dependencies which I have defined in pom.xml? If so, how do I find which one from the pom.xml is pulling them?

Comment: Those are probably transitive dependencies. run `mvn dependency:tree` to see exactly where they come from.

Comment: Perfect thanks that helped. 

[INFO] +- com.pi4j:pi4j-core:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.12.0:compile

Comment: Is there any other way to find the transient dependencies if I only have the application i.e. runnable jar file (don't think it will be possible)? or find out which jar depends on which library/dependency?

Comment: The Eclipse _Maven POM Editor_ has the tab _Dependencies Hierarchy_ for that (the tabs are shown at the bottom of the _Maven POM Editor_).

Comment: And no, you cannot compute the Maven dependencies from the flat runtime classpath since different Maven dependencies hierarchies can result in the same classpath, different Maven dependencies can refer the same JAR with maybe different transitive dependencies and different Maven repositories can contain different things. Also, the runtime classpath does not tell anything about test scope dependencies.

Comment: Thanks the POM Editor is cool.

Answer (score 0):

What was mentioned by howlger and tgdavies.

Those are probably transitive dependencies. run mvn dependency:tree to see exactly where they come from. –
tgdavies

---

The Eclipse Maven POM Editor has the tab Dependencies Hierarchy for that (the tabs are shown at the bottom of the Maven POM Editor). –
howlger
18 hours ago

And no, you cannot compute the Maven dependencies from the flat runtime classpath since different Maven dependencies hierarchies can result in the same classpath, different Maven dependencies can refer the same JAR with maybe different transitive dependencies and different Maven repositories can contain different things. Also, the runtime classpath does not tell anything about test scope dependencies. –
howlger